# Using WP_List_Table in a plugin

Tags: php, oop, wordpress, plugins

I'm not entirely familiar with OOP, but I know the basics. I'm creating a Wordpress plugin and need to create a (html) table on the plugin page. I've read that in WP 3.1 there is a class called WP_List_Table which can generate the necessary markup.

Could someone give me a very basic idea of how to use this? Do I need to create a child class in order to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create a child class to extend the properties of the parent class.  I duplicated the `wp-admin/plugins.php` and `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php` and moved those files into my plugin.

I then did the whole backwards engineering thing to make it work with the current plugin I was working on.  I also found a bug in the process that has already been reported and being worked on.

The bug is found on http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15386.

In short this never executed when the child class is executed from a plugin.

```
list($columns, $hidden) = $this->get_column_info();
```

As a work around I commented out the above code and feed the method directly with what it was looking for:

```
$columns = $this->get_columns();
$hidden  = $sortable = array();
```

If you have hidden or sortable columns you can call their methods directly as well, but I didn't need them for my implementation.

After a few hours I now understand what the class is doing and I have a working model.  and when the bug is fixed, it'll be a little nicer ;)